# HTML Placing fieldsets/Labels adjacent

Tags: html, css, label, inline, fieldset

So I have two fieldsets, wrapped in in one label that I want to display adjacent to each other. Here's my code: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5brSk/2/)

So the two fieldsets containing the input boxes and instructions respectively should appear side-by-side. What should I change/add in my code to make it work? Thanks

Comment: I'm not *entirely* sure that your mark-up is invalid, but a `fieldset` is used to group related form-elements together, I'm not convinced that they should be nested within a `label`. Also, regardless of where you click within the `fieldset` focus goes to the *first* `input`, which is definitely a user-interface snafu.

Comment: It is invalid, "Element fieldset not allowed as child of element label in this context." via http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ffiddle.jshell.net%2F5brSk%2F2%2Fshow%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

having the fieldsets `float: left;` will work fine.

look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/5brSk/2/

You will have to make sure that the container of your 2 fieldsets is large enough to hold both fieldsets next to each other, otherwise it will break (again).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the two fieldsets side by side, you can use a table structure

```
<label>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        //field set 1
      </td>
      <td>
        //field set 2
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</label>
```

Add some css to fix it in the end.
And technically there is no need for the label tag.

Answer (score 0):

Do the fieldsets styled as `display: inline-block;` ( http://jsfiddle.net/5brSk/16/ ) to get them side-by-side, and don't use a label as the parent - use it's form or a div / span. There are [countless other](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://fiddle.jshell.net/5brSk/2/show/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) things that make your code invalid though (duplicate IDs etc)